# RxJS get completed result on subscribe callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I am a RxJS beginner, and I want to make my code cleaner.

This is the code I write, I am having problem for receiving completion results.

I want to make my code cleaner, getting result in subscribe callback, without using other Subject to receive result.

Here is my code, rxjs 7.0.1:

```js
import colors from 'colors/safe';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { throttle } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface IEventTask {
    id: string,
    createdTime: number
}

let global_counter: number = 0;

const mockHTTPRequest = async (event: IEventTask) => {
    return (Promise.resolve().then(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            global.setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
        });

        if (event.id === '01') {
            throw new Error(`error: ${event.id}`);
        }

        const result = `result: ${event.id}`;
        // I don't know how to get result, so I publish to another Subscriber
        subscriber.next(result);
        return result;
    }))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    })
}

const subject = new Subject<IEventTask>();
subject
    .pipe(
        throttle(mockHTTPRequest, {
            leading: true, trailing: true
        })
    )
    .subscribe({
        next: (value) => {
            console.log(`${colors.blue(`starting`)} Task#${value.id} at: ${global_counter++}`);
        },
        error: (error) => {
            console.error(error);
        },
        complete: () => {
            // How can I get Promise resolved result here?
            console.log(`completed`);
        }
    });

// It's not the code I want to use, but I don't know how to make it easy.
const subscriber = new Subject<string>();
subscriber.subscribe((result: string) => {
    console.log(`${colors.green(`finished`)} ${result} at: ${global_counter++}`);
});

(async () => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            global.setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(true);
            }, 125);
        });

        const value: IEventTask = {
            id: (i).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
            createdTime: global_counter++
        };

        subject.next(value);
    }
})();
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to me like you want to make an HTTP request whenever `subject` (the variable) gets a new value.

So, you are using `throttle` with the idea in mind that it should wait for the HTTP request until it is complete and it should provide the returned value. Problem being, that `throttle` does not provide the latter. (see [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/throttle))

I suggest you use `switchMap` instead. It expects that the passed function returns an observable and when it emits, then switchMap will forward the value. Furthermore, it completes the inner observable whenever a new value is emitted. Which means that if the HTTP request is not yet completed, it terminates the current request and makes a new one. (see [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap))

```
import { Subject, Observable, OperatorFunction, pipe, UnaryFunction } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const mockHTTPRequest = async (event: IEventTask) => {
  return (Promise.resolve().then(async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
    });

    if (event.id === '01') {
      throw new Error(`error: ${event.id}`);
    }

    const result = `result: ${event.id}`;
    // This was needed in order to provide the id in the subscribe section
    return {
      id: event.id,
      result
    };
  }))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      // This was needed for the filter function to work
      return undefined;
    })
}

// this filters nullish values: null and undefined
function filterNullish<T>(): UnaryFunction<Observable<T | null | undefined>, Observable<T>> {
  return pipe(
    filter(x => x != null) as OperatorFunction<T | null | undefined, T>
  );
}

const subject = new Subject<IEventTask>();
subject
  .pipe(
    switchMap(mockHTTPRequest),
    filterNullish()
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (value) => {
      console.log(`starting Task#${value.id} at: ${global_counter++}`);
    },
    error: console.error,
    complete: () => {
      // How can I get Promise resolved result here?
      console.log(`completed`);
    }
  });
```

In case that you do not want to cancel a request, but rather get the result of every value passed into `subject`, then you should use look into this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50809667/12851879

**Update:**

Here is the entire code with `mergeMap` (so considering all results regardless of the duration)

```
import colors from 'colors/safe';
import { Subject, Observable, OperatorFunction, pipe, UnaryFunction } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, mergeMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface IEventTask {
  id: string,
  createdTime: number
}

let global_counter: number = 0;

function waitFor(time: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
  })
}

function filterNullish<T>(): UnaryFunction<Observable<T | null | undefined>, Observable<T>> {
  return pipe(
    filter(x => x != null) as OperatorFunction<T | null | undefined, T>
  );
}

const mockHTTPRequest = async (event: IEventTask) => {
  return (Promise.resolve().then(async () => {
    await waitFor(2000);

    if (event.id === '01') {
      throw new Error(`error: ${event.id}`);
    }

    return `result: ${event.id}`;
  }))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      return undefined;
    })
}

const subject = new Subject<IEventTask>();
subject
  .pipe(
    tap(value => console.log(`${colors.blue(`starting`)} Task#${value.id} at: ${global_counter++}`)),
    mergeMap(mockHTTPRequest),
    filterNullish()
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (result) => {
      console.log(`${colors.green(`finished`)} ${result} at: ${global_counter++}`);;
    },
    error: console.error
  });


(async () => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    await waitFor(125);

    const value: IEventTask = {
      id: (i).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
      createdTime: global_counter++
    };

    subject.next(value);
  }
})();
```